# Cython: same speed defining the static type of numpy

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, numpy, cython

I have to solve numerically a differential equation using python. Basically I have two different codes. One that is responsible for reading the initial conditions of the problem and one that makes all the account. I want to optimized the second using cython.
When I define the static types of the constants (dz, dt, i, k, j ..) to floating or int, I reduce the calculation time in a quarter. Now, when I define the static types for numpy array I have no improvement.

This is my code( .pyx):

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def explicit_cython(np.ndarray u, float kappa, float dt, float dz, np.ndarray term_const, unsigned int nz, plot_time):
    '''Cython version of explicit method'''

    #Defining C types
    cdef unsigned int i, k, j
    cdef unsigned int len_plot = len(plot_time) - 1
    cdef float lamnda = kappa*dt/dz**2

    u_out = []
    u_out.append(u.copy())

    for i in range(len_plot):
        for k in range(plot_time[i], plot_time[i+1]):
            un = u.copy()
            for j in range(1, nz-1):
                u[j] = un[j] + lamnda*(un[j+1] - 2*un[j] + un[j-1]) + term_const[j]
        u_out.append(u.copy())

    return u_out
```

And this is the setup that I use to complile.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions=[Extension("explicit_cython2",["explicit_cython2.pyx"])]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
     )
```

When I make `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`, have this warning:

```
In file included from /usr/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1728:0,
             from /usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
             from /usr/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:15,
             from explicit_cython2.c:258:
/usr/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using   deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API   NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
```

Why did not win speed by defining the static type of numpy? Why I have this warning? thx!

PD. I use python 3.4 with Anaconda in a LMDE

Comment: You need more explicit type definiton of numpy array, like `np.ndarray[np.double, ndim=2]` which helps to use C array access instead of python. Also type `plot_time` `un`. Also I guess `u.copy()` took a lot of time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) you probably won't get any benfit unless you can define the dimensions and interntal datatype of your numpy arrays

```
def explicit_cython(np.ndarray[np.float_t,ndim=2],...
```

B) I think the deprecrated warning is saying the new better interface is typed memory views http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html. If you don't want to uss those then ignore it.

C) You're probably losing a lot of speed copying stuff you immediately overwrite each step, If you can do `np.zeros(n.shape)` instead you might gain a bit. (Or even just skip the copy in the inner `for k` loop).

D) The main contents of your loop couldd be vectorised, avoiding Cython anyway.